# Un tesoro es un tesoro?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

According to my Spanish/English dictionary, "tesoro" is both the word for "treasure" (I knew that) and "thesaurus" (I didn't know that).

So how would you say, "A thesaurus is a treasure"? If you said "Un tesoro es un tesoro" would people know you meant that, or would it possibly be confused with the opposite ("A treasure is a thesaurus")?

Comment: I guess you're not talking about a _thesaurus_ = "dictionary". If it were so, the translation would be _un diccionario es un tesoro_ ("a dictionary is a treasure") which is no longer a pun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tesoro* is a generic name some authors give to their dictionaries (of any kind). For instance, Covarrubias's *Tesoro de la Lengua Castellana* is a traditional (with definitions) dictionary. *Tesoro* isn't necessarily a specific kind of dictionary.

What in English is called “thesaurus”, in Spanish is called *diccionario de sinónimos (y antónimos)*. All specialized dictionaries are generally named in the same way (*diccionario de ...*).

Recently, the term *tesauro* is being popularized as a translation of “thesaurus”, but it isn't common.

Therefore, I would translate the saying thus:

> Un diccionario de sinónimos es un tesoro.

---

“Tesoro” es un nombre genérico que algunos autores dan a sus diccionarios, del tipo que sean, como el *Tesoro de la Lengua Castellana* de Covarrubias, un diccionario tradicional (de definiciones). No es la denominación de un tipo de diccionario específico.

Lo que en inglés se llama *thesaurus* en castellano se llama “diccionario de sinónimos (y antónimos)”. Por lo general, de la misma manera (“diccionario de ...”) se llaman todos los diccionarios especializados.

En los últimos tiempos algunos traducen *thesaurus* como “tesauro”, pero no es lo más común.

Entonces, la frase quedaría así:

> Un diccionario de sinónimos es un tesoro.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Spanish for "Thesaurus" is ["Tesauro"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesauro), so the proper translation would be

> Un *tesauro* es un tesoro.

Wikipedia, says that the word

> Proviene del latín thesaurus (‘tesoro’), y este a su vez del griego clásico thesauros (θησαυρός, ‘almacén’, ‘tesorería’)

but the way to refer to this kind of dictionary of synonyms and antonyms is *tesauro* and not *tesoro*

Comment: Tesauro (al menos según el DRAE) es la forma antigua de tesoro. Yo entendería a las dos, pero suelo usar la monoptonga.

Comment: @guifa, tienes [toda la razón](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico), pero creo que si dices "tengo un tesoro" muy poca gente entenderá que a parte de tener monedas y joyas (o algo muy valioso) podrías estar diciendo que tienes un diccionario. Así que sí puedes decir "Un tesoro es un tesoro", como pregunta Clay. Lo que el oyente alcance a entender ya es otra historia.